# What were the transfer curves of major recording technology from Wax cylinders to HiFi electronics?

Tags: audio, history, recording, electro-mechanical

I am interested in the evolution of the quality / fidelity of audio recording.
Specifically in the actual frequency response curves and dynamics behavior of those technologies, not just rough ideas.
While I can find rough functional discriptions of things like

- edison wax cylinders
- early phonographs
- 78 era records

I have not found detailed information about the transfer behavior.
I have seen rough mentionings of typical bandwith of analog open reel magnetic tape recorders of the 1970's, and I guess there was probably far greater variety in quality between differently priced products when the level of technology got to "HiFi" vs. the early days of recording, so that presenting "one typical response curve" may be more difficult (or is there a good average, or worst/best corridor kinda graph?).

What I'd ideally like to see is a list of the major recording technology steps from ~1900 to, I would guess, 1970s, when quality started to get really good for high end magnetic recording devices - accompanied with typical response curves and maybe hints about special quirks / limitations, if applicable.

So that you can (primarily) visually see in what way and by how much things evolved, from tech step to tech step, if that makes sense.

This is really the level that I'm interested in with this subject. I'm interested in the "deltas".
But I can see how maybe some might see this as "too broad" a question.
If that is true, then I guess one could make a question for a "complete" list of all major recording tech evolutionary steps - and from that, branch out with further individual questions, one per recording technology, to ask for the specifics of each?

(I realize that the earliest forms with only mechanical sound reproduction are maybe out of place on EE - but, I figure from the technical knowledge held by the crowd, this is very much the most likely place, no? And it "seemlessly" grows into electrical tech... it seems historically connected)

Comment: [Have you seen this library of old wax cylinder recordings?](http://cylinders.library.ucsb.edu/browse.php)

Comment: Not 1970s but late 1940s (experimentally) or 1950s (practically) : search  "Wireless World Williamson amplifier" for one 1947 data point. Amplifiers are relatively easy though : in the "BBC Recording Training Manual" (1950 ed), most frequency responses are only measured up to 10 kHz, but when FM came along in the 50s, flat to 15 kHz was expected. Another data point : a lot of late 50s recordings are still famous and give nothing away in quality today. Miles Davis "Kind of Blue" for one.

Comment: One more data point from the above book : the Marconi-Stille recording system (on actual steel tape) was flat to about 5 kHz (-4 dB at 6 kHz) in 1934.

Comment: From Wikipedia Phonograph Record article: *In 1925, electric recording extended the recorded frequency range from acoustic recording (168–2,000 Hz) by 2 1⁄2 octaves to 100–5,000 Hz. Even so, these early electronically recorded records used the exponential-horn phonograph (see Orthophonic Victrola) for reproduction.*

Comment: Be aware that fidelity is not the only driving force, cost and convenience are important also. 78 RPM records were 10" in diameter and only contained one song on each side. Vinyl (raw material) is expensive. MP3 files are more convenient than CDs but with reduced fidelity.

Comment: While not uninteresting, this question is not a fit for this site, both because it is too broad and because it is asking about the details of consumer products, rather than being a *design* question within the mission of this site.

Comment: Be careful when comparing. I'd wondered why specs for skinny "hiFi" cassette @ 1+7/8 ips were very similar to 1/4" tape @ 3+3/4 ips. It shouldn't be so. Turns out that cassette frequency pre-compensation during recording is far more aggressive than older tape. To make it look good, cassette is measured with test tones 20 dB lower than older tape. Marketers influence the specifications.

Comment: "asking about the details of consumer products" -- rather about the state of the art through periods

Comment: Does anyone have tips for rewording of the question, if it's feasible at all?
The reason for closing doesn't seem to really fit it either - it's not about usage, it's about what was technically possible. You could say it's about what the designs of the day were capable of... alas there is no tech history SE site. (hey, could we make one? ;))

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but I can't put pictures in a comment.

You made me curious with your question, so I downloaded a few copies of random wax cylinder recordings and had a look at them with the spectrum analyzer in [Audacity.](https://www.audacityteam.org/)

I think you'll find that there is no "one true transfer function" for that kind of equipment.

[This recording of "A Hot Time in the Old Town" by Francis McCarty](http://cylinders.library.ucsb.edu/detail.php?query_type=mms_id&query=990041107630203776&r=1&of=74) has a really ratty frequency range:

[image]

It has a lot of rumble below 200 Hz, and usable audio really only from above 200Hz to close to 4000Hz.  The usable range is anything but flat.  There's like about a 3dB per octave highpass filter at 4000Hz.  Sounds like the guy is singing in a tin can.

[This recording of "Butcher's Boy" by Frank Luther](http://cylinders.library.ucsb.edu/detail.php?query_type=mms_id&query=9947925751903776&r=12&of=74) is much better:

[image]

It also has a lot of rumble below 200Hz, but above that the response is fairly flat.  The voice sounds almost normal if you can ignore the noise and the singing style.

The frequency analysis are made of the noise before each song - that's what you actually hear from the playback.  Given that these are recordings of the recordings, the transfer function is the total result of the following:

1. Original recording transfer function.
2. Original playback transfer function.
3. Modern recording transfer function.
4. Any post processing that may have been applied in an attempt to improve the recording.
5. MP3 compression artifacts.

I would make a guess that such recordings could be considered "flat" from about 200Hz to maybe 4000Hz.

I expect there was a lot of variation in the results, though.  The acoustics of the room the recordings were made in would have an influence, and I would almost bet that there were mechanical resonance and damping effects in the recording and playback machines intended to "equalize" each other.  Sort of like a mechanical "Dolby noise reduction" where you use a resonance in the recording side to make some frequencies louder to make up for a loss in the playback - or the other way around where you would use a damping effect to reduce some overly loud frequency range caused by a resonance in the recorder. That's speculation, though.

Comment: delightful answer